# Cannot boot Ubuntu 18.04. installation

Tags: 18.04, bios, rufus

I've recently embarked on the journey of web development and have heard a protip to have dual bootable OS's. Since I already run Windows 10 for day-to-day needs, I wanted to install Ubuntu (18.04) as the second OS on my laptop (I can't afford a Mac for the moment either, so there's that).

I've dusted off my long-serving USB key, downloaded the Ubuntu installer and prepared everything using Rufus 3.1. I shut the system down and started the laptop back up, holding the F12 key for the USB key to boot up the installer.

BIOS started up, but after a while of trying to load, it popped the following message:

```
PXE-E53: No boot filename received
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent
```

Afterwards, it exits the BIOS and starts booting up the Windows.

Is there anything I may have done wrong or is it a known issue with a quick fix?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you look into using Virtual Machines instead of dual-booting?

Comment: Is Windows 10 from Vendor, so UEFI or upgrade from Windows 7, so probably BIOS with MBR?  What brand/model system? What video card/chip? You probably have to turn UEFI Secure boot off, and may also need to turn on allow USB boot or USB full access or similar setting. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @user535733: Yes, I did think of running a virtual machine with Ubuntu. It's just a matter of preference that I want to dual-boot.

Comment: @oldfred: It's a HP Elitebook 8440p, upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: @oldfred: As for the GPU, it's Nvidia NVS 3100M.